# dynamically set the lookup key in a mongo findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongojs

My REST API allow the user to decide how they want to lookup an item. 
They have two options, a default and a second option.

The URL would look like:

/item/{id}

Optionally the user can pass a 'query' on the request i.e

/item/{id}?key=sku

I'm using Node.js, restify and mongoJS.  I'm trying to dynamiclly set the "key" in the query as follows:

```
    // default lookup is always id
    var queryKey = '_id';

    // if the optional 'via' query is set to sku change the lookup key
    if(viaVal === 'sku' ){
      queryKey = 'sku'
    }

   mongo.idpool.findOne({queryKey: id},
```

This causes an "illegal access" error when I'm debugging and does not work.

- What is the cause of this?
- What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax when using a variable as a property name by surrounding it in square brackets:

```
mongo.idpool.findOne({[queryKey]: id}, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sharing the link. I was trying to google for it but didn't know "computed property name" was the term to search. Thanks again!